# Converting a Virtual Address to a Physical Address

Tags: operating-system, virtualization

I am doing an OS course in college and I don't understand something I found in the slides for the course:

Consider a VM System with the following page table. The page size is 1KB.

Frame    Valid    Referenced    Modified

4         1         1              0

7         1         1              1

0         0         0              0

2         1         0              0

0         0         0              0

0         1         0              1

It then converts the following addresses into physical ones: 1052, 2221, 5499.

For 2221, it does 2221 = 2 x 1024 + 173 and then it says it maps to page #2 -> page fault.

Could anyone please explain to me why this leads to a page fault?

Comment: This line, `Frame Valid Referenced Modified 4 1 1 0 7 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1`, what does it mean, exactly?

Comment: I changed this to look appropriate, don't know why it didn't at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entry 2 (counting from 0 and up) has 0 in the valid bit. That's why you get a page fault.

Comment: I see. I didn't realise it was numbered from 0. I appreciate it.

Comment: I don't know all (or most of) the gaps in your knowledge, so it's impossible to point to specific things at the moment.